# Find matrix $S$ such that $diag(S)=d$ and $S^{-1}_{ij}=P_{ij}$ $\forall i \neq j$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I want to find a matrix $S$ with a fixed diagonal $d$ whose inverse matches $P$ on all of its off-diagonal elements.

You can assume $S$ and $P$ are positive definite, and $d>0$ (all elements of $d$ are positive).

Where this problem arises is in the following optimization:

$$\max_{S ~ s.t. ~ diag(S)=d} ~ -S \circ P + \ln | S |$$

where $\circ$ is a matrix dot product operator (multiply corresponding elements and add it all up). If it weren't for the condition that $diag(S)=d$, the solution to the maximization would be $S=P^{-1}$. However, because of the condition, we need $S^{-1}$ to match $P$ on all the off diagonal elements, while still keeping its diagonal equal to $d$.

The only solution I can think of is to just do the optimization numerically (via gradient descent or Convex Optimization / Semidefinite Programming), which is too costly computationally.

Comment: Why not compute $P^{-1}$ and replace the diagonal elements of $P^{-1}$ with $d$?

Comment: @BrianBorchers I need $diag(S)=d$, NOT $diag(S^{-1})=d$

Comment: can you guarantee existence of a solution? have you tried for small matrices?

Comment: @Surb the original optimization problem is convex, so will have one solution. And I just confirmed, for the 2x2 case, that the solution will be
$S_{12} = \frac{1 + \sqrt{1+4 d_1 d_2 P_{12}^2}}{2 P_{12}}$

Comment: ok, so you want to solve the first order condition for a critical point, right?

Comment: Sorry, in my last comment the answer should be $1 \pm \sqrt{\cdot}$, with either the plus or the minus solution keeping $S$ positive-definite.

@Surb, sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "first order condition for a critical point"...

Comment: What happens in the $2 \times 2$ case if $P_{12} = 0$?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Good point. As can been seen in my previous solution, you would have $S_{12} \to \infty$, and you basically wouldn't have a solution. So I guess I only care about how to solve this in the non-edge cases (where there is a valid solution)

Comment: @chausies I meant, that the equation in the title, is deduced by looking at the KKT conditions of the problem? Also you should edit your post to add your solution for 2x2 matrices.